# How to configure 2 Spring Kafka listeners which listen to the same topic to have their own retry and dead letter topics

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

In Spring Kafka I have two Kafka listeners listening to the same topic. I'd like both listeners to both have their own retry and dead letter topic so if failure occurs in one listener it doesn't get replayed to the other listener. With the below configuration they will both end up using the same retry and dead letter topic

- payment-topic
- payment-topic-retry
- payment-topic-dlt

```
class PaymentListener {
    
    @KafkaListener(topics = ["payment-topic"],)
    fun sendBill(payment: Payment) {
        // ...some logic
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = ["payment-topic"],)
    fun adjustBalance(payment: Payment) {
        // ...some logic
    }
}

    @Bean
    fun paymentTopicRetryStrategy(
        template: KafkaTemplate<String, ClearingFinishedEvent>,
    ): RetryTopicConfiguration {
        return RetryTopicConfigurationBuilder
            .newInstance()
            .useSingleTopicForSameIntervals()
            .fixedBackOff(3000)
            .maxAttempts(3)
            .includeTopic("payment-topic")
            .dltProcessingFailureStrategy(DltStrategy.ALWAYS_RETRY_ON_ERROR)
            .autoCreateTopics(true, 1, BROKER_DEFAULT)
            .create(template)
    }
```

What I actually want is :

- payment-topic

*[sendBill listener uses these as retry & dead letter topics]*

- send-bill-payment-topic-retry
- send-bill-payment-topic-dlt

*[adjustBalance listener uses these as retry & dead letter topics]*

- adjust-balance-payment-topic-retry
- adjust-balance-payment-topic-dlt

I could write a Custom naming strategy (https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#custom-naming-strategies) but details of the listener aren't available to me so I can't make it specific enough.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `RetryTopicConfigurationBuilder` (which filters by topic name), use `@RetryableTopic` on the listeners; you can then use a custom `retryTopicSuffix`.

You could then have something like `payment-topic-bill-retry` and `payment-topic-adjust-balance-retry`, etc.

Comment: That's still not really what I'm look for. Instead of 'payment-topic-send-bill-retry' for instance, I am looking for 'send-bill-payment-topic-retry' <prefix><topicname><suffix> or <what-i-want-retry>. I want control of the prefix too.
    
Something like this:

   @RetryableTopic(
        // doesn't exist
        dltTopicPrefix = "send-bill-",
        retryTopicPrefix = "send-bill-",
        //does-exist
        dltTopicSuffix = "-dlt",
        retryTopicSuffix = "-retry",
    )

Comment: Or something like this: Something like this:

   @RetryableTopic(
        // doesn't exist
        dltTopic = "send-bill-payment-topic-dlt",
        retryTopic = "send-bill-payment-topic-dlt-retry",
    )

Comment: It's not currently possible; as you say, there is no context provided to the custom names provider; we could enhance `Destination.Properties` to include, say, the `@KafkaListener` `id` property, but it's not available now; I provided the only work around I could think of. It's a bit unusual to have 2 listeners on the same topic, but I can see it's a valid use case; feel free to open a new feature request issue on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks Gary, I appreciate your quick response and advice.